# LibGdx Android Game Crashes on resume with odd keycode (1026)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Our LibGdx project crashes on resume, when running on android.

The following trace shows what went wrong. But cannot figure out what to do about the problem.

```
01-11 18:37:43.643  17046-17046/com.mojo.rainbowrun.android D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-11 18:37:43.643  17046-17046/com.mojo.rainbowrun.android W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41675d88)
01-11 18:37:43.643  17046-17046/com.mojo.rainbowrun.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mojo.rainbowrun.android, PID: 17046
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=256; index=1026
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.onKey(AndroidInput.java:561)
            at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7791)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2042)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1512)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2418)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1969)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3852)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3558)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3718)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2087)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1781)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1772)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2064)
            at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:196)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is a code snippet around line 561 of `AndroidInput.java`:

```
            if (keyCode == Keys.BUTTON_CIRCLE) {
                if (keys[Keys.BUTTON_CIRCLE]) {
                    keyCount--;
                    keys[Keys.BUTTON_CIRCLE] = false;
                }
            } else {
                if (keys[e.getKeyCode()]) { // Line 561
                    keyCount--;
                    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
            }
```

The `keys` array has 256 entries, so Libgdx isn't expecting a keycode as large as 1026.

Comment: Can you include a code snippet of Libgdx's AndroidInput.java around line 561 for the version you're using?  (The most recent one on github has rather different line numbers.)  Any idea what key is being pressed during resume?  Does this always happen?  Or only occasionally?  (Most likely you've got some resources that you're reusing that need to be reinitialized, but its hard to say exactly what in this case.)

Comment: added the code snippet to the bottom of my first post.

Comment: no idea what key is being pressed, just resuming the application. It doesn't happen all the time, and sometimes its happen after leaving the app for 5 min. sometimes it happens when i resume the app after leaving it for 5 sec.

Comment: Its really weird to see a keycode greater than ~250 (the keys array is allocated as `private boolean[] keys = new boolean[256];`).  1026 is 0x402, so I wonder if that is some flag value leaking in where it shouldn't.  What device is this?  Which OS version is it running and which Libgdx version are you using?

Comment: Android 4.4.4
Sony Xperia Z3 Compact
and LibGdx 1.5.2

Comment: There is some code in AndroidInput.java that is working around some weirdness with the "Circle" key on the Xperia.  See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidInput.java#L511.  I wonder if that work-around is botched or problematic around a resume?  Do you use the "Circle" key?  (And do you have that work-around in your version of Libgdx?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Line 561, the if statement has an array, and when the if statement codition executes, You are getting the keycode as the index variable which can lead to an array out of bounds like the Logcat says. If this what it causes the problem, Try changing it and sees if it solves the problem.

The **if statement** in **line 561** executes with the **else** statement. If the first **if** is **false**. Verify if you can change your code in that line and see if this is what really causing your crash, I don't know what **e** object means because you dind't posted what is his job in your code.

Comment: old question, you get the answer.